# Outlook for Mac modifier keys not recognized?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

I'm using a Microsoft sculpt ergnomic keyboard with my 2019 Macbook pro.
I have changed the modifier keys so that CTRL is now the CMD key (as this keyboard doesn't have a command key).

Keyboard shortcuts such as copy/paste, etc. work in all programs, Except Outlook. The CTRL+ENTER shortcut works to send, but when I try to use CTRL+C to copy or any of the other CTRL shortcuts like reply, forward, etc. I just hear a sound and nothing happens.

I have gone into system preferences and not only changed the modifier keys but also created shortcuts for Outlook in the App shortcuts tab.

If I use my laptop keyboard, the CMD shortcuts work.

I'm stumped as to why Outlook is the only program not accepting the new shortcuts? Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Without customisation, a Mac with a Win keyboard will recognise the 'Windows' key as Command. I'd try removing your customisation & testing it that way.

Comment: OMG that worked! How did I not know that? (I feel slightly dumb now) but thank you so much!!